# XML - attribute pairing / value checking via another attribute

Tags: c#, xml

Value of predstava from part prikazivanja needs to be pired with ID in predstave that also contains attribute naziv so the final output of my code looks like this:
"1. Vjenceslav Havel AUDIJENCIJA - 16.02.2020. u 19:00 sati"
and not like this:
"1. 2210 - 16.02.2020. u 19:00 sati"
I was told I should create a class for this to work, but I have no idiea how.

```
CODE:

    int i = 1;
    var kazaliste = XDocument.Load("XML.path");
    var predstave = from predstava in kazaliste.Descendants("prikazivanje")
    select new
    {
    predstava = (string)predstava.Attribute("predstava").Value,
    dan = (string)predstava.Attribute("pocetak_dan").Value.ToString(),
    mjesec = (string)predstava.Attribute("pocetak_mjesec").Value.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'),
    godina = (string)predstava.Attribute("pocetak_godina").Value.ToString(),
    vrijeme = (string)predstava.Attribute("pocetak_vrijeme").Value.ToString()
    };
    foreach (var predstava in predstave)
    {
        Console.Write(i);
        Console.Write(". ");
        Console.Write(predstava.predstava);
        Console.Write(" - ");
        Console.Write(predstava.dan);
        Console.Write(".");
        Console.Write(predstava.mjesec);
        Console.Write(".");
        Console.Write(predstava.godina);
        Console.Write(". u ");
        Console.Write(predstava.vrijeme);
        Console.Write(" sati");
        Console.WriteLine(" ");
        i++;
    }
```

XML file contains 3 parts:
First part:

```
<predstave>
    <predstava id="2110" naziv="Vaclav Havel AUDIJENCIJA">
        <glumci>
            <glumac>140</glumac>
            <glumac>200</glumac>
        </glumci>
    </predstava>
</predstave>
```

second part:

```
<prikazivanja>
        <prikazivanje predstava="2110" pocetak_dan="16" pocetak_mjesec="2" pocetak_godina="2020" pocetak_vrijeme="19:00"></prikazivanje>
</prikazivanja>
```

third part:

```
<glumci>
<glumac id="110" ime="Blanka" prezime="Bart"></glumac>
</glumci>
```

Comment: So far, your question is unclear and is missing the source XML, an attempt at solving your problem, and the target XML.

Comment: Is this good? I'm really sorry, I have been trying to get this solved on my own with no luck.

Comment: Now, your question is answerable. But not by me. I could answer your question in [tag:xslt], but not in [tag:C#]. Good luck, but I assume it will be answered soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can do in three instructions.  I used a dictionary with xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Dictionary<string, Predstava> dict = doc.Descendants("predstava").Select(x => new Predstava() {
                id = (string)x.Attribute("id"),
                naziv = (string)x.Attribute("naziv"),
                glumac = x.Descendants("glumac").Select(y => (int)y).ToList()
            })
            .GroupBy(x => x.id, y => y)
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());


            string[] results = doc.Descendants("prikazivanje").Select(x => string.Format("{0} - {1}.{2,2:00}.{3}. u {4} sati",
                dict[(string)x.Attribute("predstava")].naziv,
                (string)x.Attribute("pocetak_dan"),
                (int)x.Attribute("pocetak_mjesec"),
                (string)x.Attribute("pocetak_godina"),
                (string)x.Attribute("pocetak_vrijeme")
                )).ToArray();
        }
    }
    public class Predstava
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string naziv { get; set; }
        public List<int> glumac { get; set; }

    }
}
```

---

If you need to sort by date use following :

```
            string[] results = doc.Descendants("prikazivanje").Select(x => new { predstava = dict[(string)x.Attribute("predstava")].naziv, date = new DateTime(
                (int)x.Attribute("pocetak_godina"),
                (int)x.Attribute("pocetak_mjesec"),
                (int)x.Attribute("pocetak_dan"),
                int.Parse(((string)x.Attribute("pocetak_vrijeme")).Substring(0,2)),
                int.Parse(((string)x.Attribute("pocetak_vrijeme")).Substring(3,2)),
                0)})
                .OrderBy(x => x.date)
                .Select(x => string.Format("{0} - {1}",
                    x.predstava,
                    x.date.ToString(@"dd.MM.yyyy. u HH:mm \sa\ti")))
                .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! After adding print contents of array at the end I got the desired result! Just to be clear, I REALLY appriciate this, I had to learn to code in C++, C#, MySQL and .NET framework in last 9 months with .NET being my focus now, so you just saved me a bunch of headacke!

Comment: I changed the padding from ToString("0#") to a format {2,2:00}

Comment: I created a DateTime to allow sorting.

Comment: UPDATE: Would the code be similiar if I had element values of glumac in predstava (2nd part of xml) and trade them for 2 attributes of glumac "ime" and "prezime" (3rd part) with indentical id attribute value?

Comment: Yes.  Do you need to get all three pieces in same output?  You could create a second dictionary Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string,string>> where ime and prezime are the KeyValuePairs.

Comment: Yes, this should be sperate part of code which would print out naziv from predstava then based on element values of glumac in those print out ime and prezime for each element in this predstava. naziv in first line, then ime prezime in new line
ex.
Vaclav Havel AUDIJENCIJA
Glumci: Blanka Bart
            etc. for every element glumac

Comment: I updated code to make the dictionary contain all items in the node predstava.  I also modified the lookup into the dictionary : I updated code to make the dictionary contain all items in the node predstava

Comment: So i just need call class and it should output what i need?

Comment: Lookup in dictionary :  dict[(string)x.Attribute("predstava")].naziv